# Meaning of "MS1 and MS2 resolution" and "MS1 and MS2: Unit" in a tandem mass-spectrometry parameter list

Tags: terminology, mass-spectrometry, drugs, pharmacology

I'm translating a Certificate of Suitability that very briefly describes procedures used to measure several impurities in a drug substance. There is a short description of the parameters of a Gas Chromatography-MS/MS procedure to detect an impurity called NDBA.

I don't understand the final line here:

> [image]

What is the meaning of **Resolution** and especially of **Unit**? I can get by with "resolution" by simply translating it into Russian without knowing what it means, but there is no suitable Russian word to translate "Unit" - I must use either the Russian words for "Unit operation" or for "Equipment unit" or for "Measurement unit", and I have no idea what this **Unit** means in the original text.

I tried reading up on MS/MS but I haven't understood it well enough to guess the meaning of this line.

Comment: Can you ask the source who provided the method? Looks like their internal jargon. There is something unit resolution but not sure what unit means.

Comment: @M.Farooq - I'll try but I doubt that I'll get any answer, because I now work not for a single company but for a translation bureau, which gets each document from a different client, and the client may be quite distant from the original authors of the document. I'll just mark this as "impossible to translate".

Comment: @CowperKetlle, I think most probably it is equipment unit. It does not make sense in English either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "unit" probably means the size of the isolation window used in the QQQ.  The term "unit" means the nominal isolation window is 1 Da (i.e. one mass "unit") wide.

The "resolution" is a standard term in mass spectrometry, and here they are saying it is about 1 Da.